# Creating Triggers to Button on DotNet MAUI

Tags: xaml, controls, maui

### I have the following Style in .NET MAUI view

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="SpecialButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

But the trigger doesn't find the IsMouserOver property and I guess there is a property missing.

I tried to change the trigger dispatcher, but I couldn't find any trigger to be right.

Comment: The missing property is from Trigger tag, add TargetType="Button" to both your triggers.

Comment: Yes, that solved one part of my problem. But I still need to resolve this Property thing.

Comment: @TaurusSoftware forget about it.

Comment: @H.A.H. what do you mean?

Comment: @TaurusSoftware There isn't such property for a reason. Do not look for it, you wont find it.

Comment: Interesting, I just don't get why this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if this might work what you trying to achieve

```
<Style x:Key="SpecialButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- MouseOver Trigger -->
        <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>

        <!-- Click Trigger -->
        <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```